# AdMob ad showing the developing ad on some devices

Tags: android, admob

I'm using AdMob in my application, and today - a couple of hours - my application first version has been published on Google Play, and AdMob shows normal ads on my Galaxy Note 3 with Android 5.0.0 and on my Galaxy Note 8 with Android 4.4.2 and on Lenovo 4.4.2

I received a report from a friend that the ad shows the same ad appears during the developing period (As in the picture below), and he has Samsung Tab 4 runs Android 4.4.2 and also downloaded my app on another devices as htc with Android 4.4.2 and the same problem exists.

What could be the reason of the problem? Knowing that the application has been installed on all these devices from the same source on Google Play.

[image]

And tapping on the ad opens google developers page below:

[image]

Comment: did u forgot to change the ID from test ad to production ad ?

Comment: I didn't ... I changed both the code that initialize the ad and changed the ID to the production ID, otherwise the problem would've been on all devices.

Comment: Check with your friend in what view he sees those test ads, and then check that view if you also see it.

Comment: Have you accidentally marked some devices as test devices? https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder.html#addTestDevice(java.lang.String)
Or, knowing Google, there could also be a fail-safe. If you're friend is one of the few people, maybe Google classifies it as a test device automatically.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, it's really appreciated ... I found the reason of the problem and solved it ... I have my app localized to another language than English, and I set the ID in both langs files, but I forgot to change it to production ID in the localized file, that's why on my devices it worked well as I use English UI, and didn't work on some devices as they use the localized language for their UI, which leads to load the developing ID ... Anyway, I removed the ID from the localized resource file so the system uses the one in English resource file for all langs and it worked.

Comment: BTW, how to close the question? Do I put my finding as an answer and accept it? or there is an option to close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help, it's really appreciated ... I found the reason of the problem and solved it ... I have my app localized to another language than English, and I set the ID in both langs files, but I forgot to change it to production ID in the localized file, that's why on my devices it worked well as I use English UI, and didn't work on some devices as they use the localized language for their UI, which leads to load the developing ID ... Anyway, I removed the ID from the localized resource file so the system uses the one in English resource file for all langs and it worked.